# R - Match column by other columns in same data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, merge, match

In the following dataframe I want to create a new column called D2 that matches the corresponding A, B, or C column. For example, if D == A, I want D2 == A2.

```
A   A2  B   B2  C   C2  D
1   10  2   90  3   9   1
1   11  2   99  3   15  1
1   42  2   2   3   9   2
1   5   2   54  3   235 2
1   13  2   20  3   10  3
1   6   2   1   3   4   3
```

This is what I want the new data frame to look like:

```
A   A2  B   B2  C   C2  D   D2
1   10  2   90  3   9   1   10
1   11  2   99  3   15  1   11
1   42  2   2   3   9   2   2
1   5   2   54  3   235 2   54
1   13  2   20  3   10  3   10
1   6   2   1   3   4   3   4
```

I have succeeded in doing this with ifelse statements using dplyr, but because I am doing this with  many columns, it gets tedious after a while. I was wondering if there is a more clever way to accomplish the same task.

```
library(dplyr)  

newdata <- olddata %>% mutate(D2=ifelse(D==A,A2,ifelse(D==B,B2,C2)))
```

Comment: Is `df[c("A2","B2","C2")][cbind(1:nrow(df), df$D)]` flexible enough?

Comment: @thelatemail :  that one is a nice single liner.

Comment: @thelatemail That is cute but I think the OP made a simplistic example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this efficiently with `max.col` from `base R`.  Subset the 'olddata' with only 'A', 'B', 'C' columns ('d1'), check whether it is equal to 'D' (after replicating the 'D' to match the lengths), use `max.col` to find the index of the maximum element (i.e TRUE in this case, assuming that there will be a single TRUE value per rows), multiply by 2 as the 'A1', 'B2', 'C2' columns are alternating after 'A', 'B', 'C', `cbind` with the row sequence to create the row/column index and extract the elements based on that to create the 'D2' column.

```
d1 <- olddata[c("A", "B", "C")]
olddata$D2 <- olddata[cbind(1:nrow(d1), max.col(d1 == rep(olddata["D"], 
          ncol(d1)), "first")*2)]
olddata$D2
#[1] 10 11  2 54 10  4
```

---

A slightly different approach would be to compare the columns separately in a loop using `lapply` (should be efficient if the dataset is very big as converting to a big logical `matrix` can cost the memory) and based on that we subset the corresponding columns of A2, B2, C2 with `mapply`

```
i1 <- grep("^[^D]", names(olddata)) #create an index for columns that are not D
i2 <- seq(1, ncol(olddata[i1]), by = 2)#for subsetting A, B, C
i3 <- seq(2, ncol(olddata[i1]), by = 2)# for subsetting A2, B2, C2
olddata$D2 <- c(mapply(`[`, olddata[i3], lapply(olddata[i2], `==`, olddata$D)))
olddata$D2
[1] 10 11  2 54 10  4
```